# Angular 6 code conversion with backend reading

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have been trying to convert these method to the latest Angular 6 version of this code. My back-end sends a JSON file to the Angular application this method takes this JSON file and makes it so I can read it for my HTML. But sadly I do not understand how to refactor this code to Angular 6 since you can't use neither `.interval` nor `.map`.

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
      return Observable
      .interval(5000)
      .flatMap(() => this.http.get(this.heroesUrl).map((data) => data.json()));
  }
```

Comment: I believe you have to wrap you operators in a pipe operator. The problem is not that you are migrating to a newer version of Angular, but rather that you are migrating to a newer version of RXJS, version 6.

Comment: Why do you need interval?

Answer (score 0):

Your code would look something like this:

```
import {interval, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {flatMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  interval(500)
    .pipe(
      flatMap(() => this.http
        .get(this.heroesUrl)
        .pipe(map(data => data.json()))
      })
    );
}
```

The idea is simple; all `Observable`, `Subject`,.. and methods that create observables are imported directly from `rxjs`.
And you cannot just chain operators on the observable object anymore, you need to use the `pipe` method and place all your operators in there. Operators are imported from `rxjs/operators`

Sidenote, as you are doing `data.json()` I assume you are still using the "old" http methods, you should start using `httpClient.get` instead (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

Also, when upgrading to Rxjs 6, you can install a migration script which actually does this automatically for you

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

// mockup Hero type
export class Hero {
  constructor(public name: string, public job: string) {}
}

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private heroesUrl = 'REMOTE_SERVER_URL';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl).pipe(map((data: Hero[]) => {
        console.log(data);

        // Do something here to cast data to Hero[] model if data is not so
        return data;
      }));
  }
}
```